# Typescript singleton with method execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, oop

How is it possible to make a singleton or even normal instance that will force calling a specific method?

For example:

```
logger.instance().configure({ logs: true });
```

OR

```
new logger();
logger.configure({ logs: true });
```

If calling for a logger without the configure method chained it’ll throw an Error.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you do something like `logger.configure({logs: true})` and that returns the instance?

Comment: class logger {
    constructor() {
        this.configure({ logs: true })
    }
}

Comment: If you wanted to do it anyways, it's [extremely unwieldy](https://tsplay.dev/WzeQkm) and hard to read.

Comment: @Deckerz how should I do it in the correct way?

Comment: Sounds like you just want `logger({ logs: true })`. Since it's a singleton, there's no reason for making it a class since there will only be one instance. And there's no reason to make it an object either, since you want to provide only one method. So logger should be a basic function.

Comment: Typically when people look for static members or singletons in Javavscript, it's because they come from Java, C# or PHP where everything has to be a class. This is not the case in Javascript and you should avoid these constructs!

Comment: @Evert what do you recommend to use instead?

Comment: @Shilly I agree with you. I think I’ll use function

Comment: Try to use functions wherever you can, and only use classes if you need to push behavior + state around. Functions should be your 'default' tool, and use a class if you have a specific need for the features classes offer.

Comment: @Evert what do you mean by saying behavior and state around? Can you please give some example?

Comment: What do _you_ think the purpose of classes and instances of classes are? It's a big topic that doesn't fit in a stackoverflow comment.

Comment: @Evert yes but most of the things can be implemented in functional programming

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we want to create a singleton, we need to hide constructor. We make constructor `private`. Why? It is necessary to avoid many instances of classes.
But next question can come to people's mind: "How to initialize variables?". We can do it through `configure` method:

```
class MyLogger
{
    logs: boolean
    private static _instance: MyLogger;

    private constructor()
    {
    }

    public static get Instance()
    {
        return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());
    }

    public configure({logs}){
        this.logs = logs
    }
}

const mySingletonInstance = MyLogger.Instance;
```

And you can configure it like this:

```
const mySingletonInstance = MyLogger.Instance.configure({logs: true});
```